# Authenticating android with google firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am trying to authenticate my app with google sign in.

When I try to do this I get the **error** `Google Sign In failed. Status = Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}`

I have generated a SHA1 key and have the Google Auth enabled on the FireBase console.

I am a beginner with the authentication side of Android.

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    View.OnClickListener {

private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static final String TAG = "RegisterActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    // Get FireBase mFirebaseAuth instance
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        Log.e("45hh", "User logged in already...");
        startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    }


    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    final EditText txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    final EditText txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    Button btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    Button btnGSignin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGSignin);
    TextView txtAlreadyHaveAccount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlreadyHaveAccount);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = txtEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = txtPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (password.length() < 6) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // Create user
            mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Successfully registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication failed. " + task.getResult(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });

    btnGSignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signIn();
        }
    });

    txtAlreadyHaveAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
    });
}

private void handleFirebaseAuthResult(AuthResult authResult) {
    if (authResult != null) {
        // Welcome the user
        FirebaseUser user = authResult.getUser();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome " + user.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Go back to the main activity
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 9001);
    showProgressDialog();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == 9001) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            if(mProgressDialog!=null){
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
            // Google Sign In failed
            Log.e(TAG, "Google Sign In failed. Status = " + result.getStatus());
        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGooogle:" + acct.getId());
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication Success. Please Wait",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            });
}

public void showProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    mProgressDialog.show();
}

public void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
    // be available.
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is not working is because the ClientID was not specified. This is how it should be done:

```
private static final String googleClientID = "Enter-ClientID-Here";

GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(googleClientID)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

**You have to get your client ID from here:**
(Go to the FireBase Console -> Authentication -> Sign-In Method -> Google -> Hit the Web SDK configuration dropdown -> Web Client ID)

[image: Google ClientID Location]

**P.S.** Make sure you add the following permissions to you manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

**Hope this helps someone.**

Answer (score 0):

Just Follow these Steps for Google SignIn:

1.) Create a Project at Google Developers Console

Log in to Google Plus account and click on create project.[Creating google project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w7Ix.png)

2.) Fill the details according to your choice, Then

Now we need a configuration file for our android app.Select your app we just created on developer console. And write the package name of your android studio project you had created. Finally choose country and click on continue.

3.) Hit this command to Cmd for finding the SHA1 key.

For windows:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

For Linux:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Copy the SHA1 and paste it to the Enable Google Services Page.

Now click on Enable Google Signin. And click on Continue to Generate Configuration Files. Now click on download google-services.json to get your configuration file. Now come to android studio.

Copy the json configuration file (you just downloaded) and paste it  inside your google login android studio project (Inside app/ directory).
Like this [configuration file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53k2T.png)

Open the Top Level build.gradle file and add the following line inside dependencies.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

Inside build.gradle file add the following dependencies and sync your google login android project.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0' // this is for fetching the profile image of the user
```

Now come to activity_main.xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <TextView
        android:text="email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewEmail"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now come to MainActivity.java and write the following code.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    //Signin button
    private SignInButton signInButton;

    //Signing Options
    private GoogleSignInOptions gso;

    //google api client
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    //Signin constant to check the activity result
    private int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;

    //TextViews
    private TextView textViewName;
    private TextView textViewEmail;
    private NetworkImageView profilePhoto;

    //Image Loader
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initializing Views
        textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
        profilePhoto = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);

        //Initializing google signin option
        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        //Initializing signinbutton
        signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
        signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());

        //Initializing google api client
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();


        //Setting onclick listener to signing button
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    //This function will option signing intent
    private void signIn() {
        //Creating an intent
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);

        //Starting intent for result
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //If signin
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            //Calling a new function to handle signin
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }


    //After the signing we are calling this function
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        //If the login succeed
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            //Getting google account
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            //Displaying name and email
            textViewName.setText(acct.getDisplayName());
            textViewEmail.setText(acct.getEmail());

            //Initializing image loader
            imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext())
                    .getImageLoader();

            imageLoader.get(acct.getPhotoUrl().toString(),
                    ImageLoader.getImageListener(profilePhoto,
                            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                            R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

            //Loading image
            profilePhoto.setImageUrl(acct.getPhotoUrl().toString(), imageLoader);

        } else {
            //If login fails
            Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == signInButton) {
            //Calling signin
            signIn();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

For loading image from URL I have used a Custom Volley Request.For the custom volley request you have to create the following class.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;

import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Network;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;


public class CustomVolleyRequest {

    private static CustomVolleyRequest customVolleyRequest;
    private static Context context;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;


    private CustomVolleyRequest(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized CustomVolleyRequest getInstance(Context context) {
        if (customVolleyRequest == null) {
            customVolleyRequest = new CustomVolleyRequest(context);
        }
        return customVolleyRequest;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(context.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
            requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
            requestQueue.start();
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoader;
    }
```

Now add internet permission to your manifest and  run your google login android application.

This,is all the full process for G-SignIn Authentication !!!